# What is the difference between Access Token , SID , Impersonation Token?

Tags: windows, security, permissions

I've listed the definitions picked up from MSDN but I'd like to know the difference between these with an example of a program(process) that might need to make use of them in different scenarios.

**ACCESS TOKEN**

> An access token is an object that describes the security context of a
>   process or thread. The information in a token includes the identity
>   and privileges of the user account associated with the process or
>   thread. When a user logs on, the system verifies the user's password
>   by comparing it with information stored in a security database. If the
>   password is authenticated, the system produces an access token. Every
>   process executed on behalf of this user has a copy of this access
>   token

**SID**

> A security identifier (SID) is a unique value of variable length used
>   to identify a trustee. Each account has a unique SID issued by an
>   authority, such as a Windows domain controller, and stored in a
>   security database. Each time a user logs on, the system retrieves the
>   SID for that user from the database and places it in the access token
>   for that user. The system uses the SID in the access token to identify
>   the user in all subsequent interactions with Windows security.

**IMPERSONATION TOKEN**

> An access token that has been created to capture the security
>   information of a client process, allowing a server to "impersonate"
>   the client process in security operations.

Based on the definition they all seem to be pretty similar sounding to me. Can someone please explain the differences between these by giving an example ?

Answer (score 4):

"SID" is a static identifier attached to a user account. It is just a series of numbers, like a person's [SSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number) / [NIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number), or a database record's "primary key". Since it never changes, its purpose is to find a specific account even though it might have been renamed; for that reason, it is stored instead of the user name in tokens, ACLs, and other similar structures.

Note that there are also group SIDs, session SIDs, service SIDs, and such – for identifying all sorts of different "actors" which may be in ACLs.

"Token" is a [kernel object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) containing lists of SIDs and privileges. The kernel has very strict rules for obtaining and manipulating them (this can be done only using syscalls, not direct memory access), so having a token means the process was allowed to act on behalf of whatever user that token describes.

(On Unix-like systems, if you're familiar with them, a process has a set of "credentials" – 'real UID', 'effective UID', 'real GID', 'effective GID', 'supplementary GIDs', and a few other things. The SID is an extension of an UID/GID, and the token is a collection of these credentials. Instead of calling `capset()`+`setgroups()`+`setgid()`+`setuid()`, you obtain a token and call `SetToken()`.)

There are two kinds of tokens – "primary", which can be generated only by logging in to the system, and "[impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391(v=vs.85).aspx)", temporary tokens that any service can create to act on behalf of a client.

Here's a [full list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx) of all information kept in a token.